# JavaScript time independent of client PC's time

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to get the current UTC time without relying on the time and timezone of the client's pc? I am not allowed to use PHP or anything from the server side for this (Using a hosted service and they only allow changing of HTML and addition of JavaScript. Not allowed to change PHP on the server.). Must be only done from the client side via JavaScript.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions / solutions.

If my question is not clear, please let me know what else would make it clearer and I will add those details.

Best regards,
Tony.

Comment: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/javascript-get-timezone-offset/

Comment: If you can't rely on the client time and are not allowed to use server-side support either, you don't have many more options aside from a web service accessible via JSONP, which won't be accurate thanks to network latency; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549079/world-clock-webservice

Comment: Thanks Kai for your suggestion. Accessing a web service was not an option in my case. But the time didn't have to be so accurate. Just +/- 2 mins is more than enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, JavaScript can only give you the client time, or a value provided by the server (e.g. a special hidden `utcTime` input element). You have ruled out the latter.

However, for dynamic pages, [`document.lastModified`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/lastModified) may be a close approximation to the current server time. This is based on the [Last-Modified](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.29) header.

Comment: Thank you. I think I will use the lastModified as you have mentioned.